Call htmx:after-on-load after successful hx-post
I have a form in a boostrap modal that I am posting with HTMX.  The post is working great and so is validation.  The problem is the successful submit response.  I am returning ASP.NET MVC Ok(); method which returns 200.
I want the modal to close after 200.
I tried this code:
<form
hx-post="@Url.Action("Edit", "Vendors", new { Model.Vendor.VendorId })"
hx-target="#edit-vendor-form-container"
hx-encoding='multipart/form-data'
hx-on:htmx:after-on-load="$('#edit-vendor-modal').modal('hide');"

It is not working.  Why?
I tried hx-on:htmx:afterOnLoad and hx-on:htmx:after-request, but neither worked.  I confirmed that the jQuery code to close the modal is correct by pasting it into Developer Tools.  (I'm on Bootstrap 4).

There are no log messages either.

Is the form inside of #edit-vendor-form-container? Try putting the hx-onattribute on a parent, such as #edit-vendor-form-container. It will bubble up.

@BenderBoy - it worked!  How would I have known this from the documentation?  Oh well.  Thank you!  Please make an answer and I will accept it.

Shoot.  It also triggers when there is a validation error in the form.  That is not what I wanted.

I found an answer.
I removed hx-on:htmx:after-on-load="$('#edit-vendor-modal').modal('hide');"
Instead I return a HX-Trigger header in my response like this (C# code):
Response.Headers.Append("HX-Trigger", "close-active-modal");
return NoContent();

This will cause HTMX to emit an event which you can handle in JavaScript.
Then I have a bit of javascript to handle the event.  I wish I did not have to do this as the whole point of HTMX (for me) is to handle common AJAX patterns without custom JS.  At least I only need a few lines of JS and this can be reused.
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    document.body.addEventListener("close-active-modal", function () {
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    });
});


HTMX does not seem to care which return code I use as long as it is 2XX.  So I returned 204, not content, as recommended here: https://htmx.org/docs/#requests
